# Why was this edit rolled back?

Tags: discussion

I edited this [answer](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/121198/150566) to fix a mistake in english grammar as well as a powershell syntax error. I believe my edit is correct but the answerer has rolled it back. As of now, the script in the answer is back to not working. Should I do anything further or forget about it?

Comment: Why don't you ask Shawn in a comment on the answer? I mean, the rest of us can't know why he rolled your edit back, and I don't know how active he is here on meta.

Comment: There was no mistake in my English and I can't decline partial edits.

Comment: You might ask for the reason (though Shawn has provided their reason above), but it's the OP's privilege to rollback any edits applied to their own posts. If that's the case, then just ignore it and move on.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your edit was **correct in both respects**.

It is a shame it was retrospectively rejected by the post author, after being [narrowly approved](https://dba.stackexchange.com/review/suggested-edits/131314) by the first three reviewers.

The author has now corrected the script as you suggested, but the [ungrammatical](https://www.dictionary.com/e/pique-peak-peek/) "peaks my interest" is still present.

Perhaps the edit was rejected (instead of improved) in a [fit of pique](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/pique)

It's not worth arguing over though. At least the code is functional now.

If you feel it is worthwhile, you could add a separate answer.